# Error using BeautifulSoup code to retrieve info from cooking website. Issues parsing HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to create a program that will bring back the Title, URL, Ingredients, and Recipe Instructions from recipes listed in the allrecipes.com sitemap. However, I'm missing something for the Ingredients and Recipe sections of my code. They are in list format in the html code and I'm having trouble getting the html parsed to usable data. I'm trying to do it correctly for one specific page before I start doing it for multiple.
I am extremely new to BS4, so any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


def scrape_recipe_data(url):
    # Make an HTTP request to the provided URL

    response = requests.get(url)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Extract title
        title_tag = soup.title
        title_text = title_tag.text if title_tag else "No title found in the HTML document"
        print("Title:", title_text)

        ingredients_element = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json', 'title': 'recipeIngredient'}) 

        if ingredients_element:
            ingredients_data = json.loads(ingredients_element.string)
            ingredients = ingredients_data if isinstance(ingredients_data, list) else[]
            print("Ingredients:", ingredients)
        else:
            print("No ingredients found in the HTML document")
        directions_element = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json', 'title': 'recipeInstructions'})  

        if directions_element:
            directions_data = json.loads(directions_element.string)
            directions = directions_data if isinstance(directions_data, list) else[]
            print("Directions:", directions)
        else:
            print("No directions found in the HTML document")


    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve the page. Status code:", response.status_code)


url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/276505/grandmas-hash-brown-casserole/"
scrape_recipe_data(url)
```

The output I get is usually this:

```
Title: Grandma's Hash Brown Casserole Recipe
No ingredients found in the HTML document
No directions found in the HTML document

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What's the full error? The only call to `get` in this code is on the `requests` module.

Comment: Apologies for the mixup, I had started typing this question much earlier, when I was using scrapy for the program. I have since switched to BeautifulSoup. I am simply trying to get the HTML for the ingredients and directions to return in a more legible format.

Comment: did you check what you have in `response.text`? Some servers may send different HTML for different browser and tools, and for programs which can't run JavaScript.

Comment: I see some `<script>` with `application/ld+json` but they don't have `title`.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to debug, instead of making a new request every time you changed your code, you can write the response to a file and then simply read the file and load it to soup.

With that said, check what you are trying to `.find()` and whats in the html.

In your code, your line `ingredients_element = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json', 'title': 'recipeIngredient'})` you are tring to find a `<script>` in the html with the attributes `type="application/ld+json"` and `title="recipeIngredient"` but if you check the HTML it doesn't have a `title` attribute, so it fails to find one which is why you are getting no ingredient list found. `recipeIngredient` and `recipeInstructions` only exist inside the `<script>` when you use `json.loads()`.

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_recipe_data(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url,
            timeout=10,
            headers={
                "Accept": "text/html",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            },
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. {err}")
        return
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # Extract title
    title_tag = soup.title
    title_text = title_tag.text if title_tag else "No title found in the HTML document"
    print("Title:", title_text)

    recipe_elements = soup.find("script", attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})
    if not recipe_elements:
        print("No recipe found in the HTML document")
        return

    recipe_data = json.loads(recipe_elements.string)

    try:
        print("Ingredients:", recipe_data[0].get("recipeIngredient", []))
        print(
            "Directions:",
            [
                step.get("text", [])
                for step in recipe_data[0].get("recipeInstructions", [])
            ],
        )
    except KeyError:
        print("Expected a list for the `recipe_data` and didn't get one")


url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/276505/grandmas-hash-brown-casserole/"
scrape_recipe_data(url)
```

What I did was first, add a 10 second timeout to the request. This is important as your script could be stuck indefinitely trying to get something without ever getting an error (had to add headers too as I was getting 4xx status code). I added a try/except to the request block with a `.raise_for_status()` which will raise an exception if the status code is 4xx or 5xx.

Then, since the HTML only contains 1 `<script type="application/ld+json">` element with the instructions and ingredients in a json format, we need to *find* it only once. which is why i'm saving it to a variable and checking if its empty or not. `recipe_elements = soup.find("script", attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})`

Then I load that data using `json.loads()` so it can be manipulated with Python and access the `recipeIngredient` and `recipeInstructions` keys of the json we just loaded. Because `Directions` is a list of dictionary of steps, I used [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list with only the text of the different steps.